How to bind to two different contexts
I have a UserControl whose xaml looks roughly like this:
<UserControl x:Class="...OptionalReferenceBlock" ...>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind references, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:OptionalReference">
                <local1:TableView tableProvider="{x:Bind ??, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>

OptionalReferenceBlock defines two properties: value; and references which is a list of OptionalReferences.   OptionalReference contains  (among others) a property Partial partial.  Like this:
public class OptionalReference {
    public Partial partial { get; init; }
}

public sealed partial class OptionalReferenceBlock : UserControl {

    public OptionalReferenceBlock() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    IEnumerable<OptionalReference> references {
        get => (IEnumerable<OptionalReference>)GetValue(referencesProperty);
        set => SetValue(referencesProperty, value);
    }

    public static DependencyProperty referencesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(references),
        typeof(IEnumerable<OptionalReference>),
        typeof(OptionalReferenceBlock),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );


    IVisibleDataType value {
        get => (IVisibleDataType)GetValue(valueProperty);
        set => SetValue(valueProperty, value);
    }

    public static DependencyProperty valueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(value),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(OptionalReferenceBlock),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

}

Just to make this clear: the list of OptionalReferences - and the individual OptionalReferences themselves - are set just once, but value is repeatedly changed (This appears inside a DataGrid: OptionalReferences is defined ultimately by the column, but value is constantly being rebound).
The TableView control has a tableProvider property whose type is TableProvider.  Neither partial nor value is of that type, but partial.with(value) is.  My question, then, is: what do I need to bind to the tableProvider property to make this work?
I've tried something along the lines of x:Bind partial.with(value), but that doesn't work because partial and value come from two different data contexts, and I can't really see how to refer to them at the same time.
I tried to create a value converter, like this:
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:PartialToTableProviderConverter x:Key="PartialConverter" value="{x:Bind value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

and then x:Bind partial Converter={StaticResource PartialConverter} but that doesn't work because (as far as I can tell) it's not possible to provide a value converter with a bound property (You can define it, but the runtime errors: vide here.
MultiBindings might solve this, but not on Winui 3.
Is there some syntax I'm missing, or is what I'm trying to accomplish fundamentally flawed?

I don't understand your question very well. Please try to create a minimal sample and share the code here.

Your class name is very confusing. I recommend you not to use the language reserved words.
